# publish the ASP.NET MVC 3 project in bluehost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, publish, host, bluehost

I've designed a website using ASP.net MVC 3. 
I wanted to host it online.
But as copied all the folders and files and uploaded in Bluehost [via FTP Manager], the page doesn't load. It still shows the template of Bluehost.

What all files should I copy? or Won't it work when I just upload them? do I have to follow any other steps?

Comment: Bluehost does not support aspnet, AFAIK.  Not sure if they support Mono, otherwise you will need to deploy to a Windows host

Comment: Mono:  http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page    A cross-platform implementation of .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluehost does not support ASPNet or MVC.

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/197

You need to try other hosting company that supports Windows hosting.  There are a ton, but Bluehost does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bluehost only offer Linux Based hosting and you can only run application which are developed on LAMP. If you want to host a website developed using .NET technology you can go for Godaddy, Hostgator or any host which offer Asp.NET hosting.

You can check some hosting recommendations here http://freeasp.net